# Will the public key affected, when I change my Git config username?

Tags: git, ssh

I generated a private and public key with SSH. But now I would like to change my Git username in

> git config --global user.name "John Doe"

Will this affect my SSH keys, which I used earlier to get access to a remote repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not affect how you push or pull changes in any way.

This setting only changes how you are identified in the commits you make locally. This data is usually not used for any authentication means but only affects what authorship information is show for your commits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: However there are repository management systems, which might check and compare the author name to the user account where the SSH key is assigned to (e.g. Bitbucket can do this). So if you're using such a system, you might want to check that everything works afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I tried to convey with "usually not used" :) I also think, it is a quite bad idea to rely on committer information for push-authorization since it makes e.g. rebases and other history-changing operations quite hard if not impossible to pull off.